# Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'

Tags: php, redbeanphp

r_db code:

```
<?php 
require "rb.php";

R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=register',
        'root', 'root' );

?>
```

login.php code:

```
<?php
require "r_db.php";

$data = $_POST;

if( isset($data['do_login']) )
{
    $errors = array();
    $user = R::find('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']
        ));
    if ( $user ) {
        if ( password_verify($data['password'], $user->password) ) {
             
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'password enocen';
        }
    }else{
        $errors[] = ' user with this login doesn`t find';
    }
    if( ! empty($errors)){
        echo '<div style="color:red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
    }
}
?>
```

ERROR: Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'.
Что за ошибка и как его исправить?
[image: Eror]

Comment: Ожидался объект, а дали массив

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.